# DBpedia/Yago integration

Tags: dbpedia

My understanding is that DBpedia takes from YAGO the class hierarchy, not the entities, as per http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets. However, something like http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/AlbertEinstein or http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Europe, correspond to YAGO entities, not classes. Those are easy to identify, the usually have the rdfs:label property only.

Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 2):

[YAGO: A Core of Semantic Knowledge Unifying WordNet and Wikipedia](http://suchanek.name/work/publications/www2007.pdf) says:

> Classes are also entities. Thus, each class is itself an instance
>   of a class, namely of the **class** class.

Answer (score 1):

In RDF, Everything is either a resource, a property, or a Literal. Entities and classes are considered Resources. 
DBPedia maps the entities to multiple types, including the ones in YAGO. It also has the Wikipedia categories that you can query using `dcterms:subject`.